# Why does the sign "µ" get replaced by "?" in variable names throughout my R script files?

Tags: corruption, mu

Sometimes when I open my old R script files to re run my modelling all the variable names containing the sign "µ" are replaced by the same variable names but with "µ" replaced by "?". This does not happen all the time nor does it happen to all the files which are saved in the same folder in the same format.

When it has happened changing back to all "?" to "µ" results in error when trying to access variables with names containing "µ" which were defined in other scripts for which this "µ" to "?" conversion never happened. These errors do not occur until after this corruption from "µ" to "?" has occurred.

Example error:
Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `C_Free_µg.L = sum(C_Free_POM_µg.L, na.rm = TRUE)`.
ℹ In group 1: `Key = "AAB1"`, `Soil = "None"`, `Replicate = "1"`, `Series = "AAB"`, `Series_Name = "100 % Asphalt A"`.
Caused by error:
! object 'C_Free_POM_µg.L' not found

I'm unable to produce a minimal working example as the error only appears after corruption.